# ItemTapped / ItemSelected not triggering in ListView - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, uitapgesturerecognizer, selecteditem

I am working on a ListView that has two Labels and Horizontal List(with TapGestureRecognizer applied only to the horizontal list) in its cell view.

I have implemented ItemTapped/ItemSelected to get the index value of selected item of ListView and tested with break points working fine.

The issue is that the Events are not getting triggered when I tap/select on the Horizontal List, they are getting triggered only when I tap/select on other space of item except the Horizontal List.

Code for ItemTapped

```
                    int lvIndex;
                    timePlannerLV.ItemTapped += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        lvIndex = itemLV.IndexOf(e.Item as LVItem);            
                    };
```

Code for ItemSelected

```
                    int lvIndex;
                    timePlannerLV.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        lvIndex = itemLV.IndexOf(e.SelectedItem as LVItem);        
                    };
```

I want the event to trigger when I tap anywhere in the item of ListView.

Any help would be greatly appreciable.. Thanks in advance ..

Comment: The TapGestureRecognizer probably takes precedent over the ListViews tapped events which means that they won't be triggered. What I don't quite get is this Horizontal List you're referring to, there's no such control in Xamarin Forms currently. Is that something custom made?

Comment: yes it is custom made.. How can I solve this, is there any way ?

Comment: why do you use TGR for your labels in your ViewCell?

Comment: I used tap gesture only to the horizontal list.. not for labels

Comment: But why the tap gesture recognizer? I assume it's in there to have some behaviour when tapping on a Horizontal List item. The gesture recognizer handles the taps on those and everything else is handled by the ListView tap. Of the ListView would also have to trigger on the Horizontal List item It would never be able to distinguish which Command you meant to trigger.

Comment: I applied tap gesture recogniser on horizontal list to get a value from list when tapped and display it in label.. ok so you are saying that both the ItemTapped of ListView and TapGesture of Horizontal List are getting clashed and so only the TapGesture is triggering there.. right?

Comment: That's what is probably happening yeah.